# Is there a way to get a list of file names and the first line of text listed on the same line in Linux?

Tags: linux, text, head

I am trying to get a list of file names in a directory and the first line of text from each file and output each pair to a single line to be output to a .csv file.

I have tried a bunch of different methods of using head, ls, find, and grep and combinations of these but can't seem to get the results to print onto a single line. Closest I have gotten was getting them to print on separate lines.

Here is an example of the output I would need:

```
filename1.txt "this is the first line of text"
filename2.txt "this is the first line of text"
```

I'm not really concerned with having extra characters or anything in the results, as I can edit that out easily in Excel once I have them on the same line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for ... but see if [paste](https://linux.die.net/man/1/paste) might help

Answer (score 11):

To obtain filenames and first lines for all files in the directory, try:

```
awk '{print FILENAME" \"" $0"\""; nextfile}' *
```

To obtain filenames and first lines for all files whose names start with 328, try:

```
awk '{print FILENAME" \"" $0"\""; nextfile}' 328*
```

#### Example

Consider a directory with these two files:

```
$ cat filename1.txt
this is the first line of text
2
3
$ cat filename2.txt
this is the first line of text
b
c
```

Now, run our command:

```
$ awk '{print FILENAME" \"" $0"\""; nextfile}' *
filename1.txt "this is the first line of text"
filename2.txt "this is the first line of text"
```

#### How it works

- `awk '{...}' *

  This starts `awk` and runs the commands inside the curly braces.  With the glob `*`, this is run for all files.  The glob can be limited to, for example, `328*.txt` to work on all files whose names start with `328` and end with `.txt`.

  By default awk will read one line at a time for each file in turn.
- `print FILENAME" \"" $0"\""`

  This tells awk to print the filename followed by `"` followed by the first line, `$0`, followed by another `"`.
- `nextfile`

  Since we have no interest in reading the second line, this tells awk to skip to the next file.

#### Saving to file

We can save the first lines to a file like this:

```
$ awk '{print FILENAME" \"" $0"\""; nextfile}' *.txt >output.txt
```

The `output.txt` file looks like:

```
$ cat output.txt
filename1.txt "this is the first line of text"
filename2.txt "this is the first line of text"
```

Comment: This actually works really well and is definitely working. Only issue is that when I try to output to the csv its only writing the first result. Any suggestions? And thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: @ThomasHoppenreys  I can't reproduce that.  I just added an example of saving to a file to the end of the answer.  As you can see, when I run it, I get both lines.  If you see something different, I would like more details on exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out. when I cat the file from Linux command line it shows all of the lines in the file, but when I open it in Excel on Windows its only showing the first line. Know of any work around so that I can edit the file in Excel?

Comment: @ThomasHoppenreys  I don't have either Windows or excel so I'm not sure what to suggest.  It could be a line ending issue.  If you have `unix2dos` or similar conversion program you could try that but I have no way to test to see if this is the problem.  (I tried opening it on Linux with the LibreOffice spreadsheet and it shows the multiple rows just fine.)

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for the information. I should be able to figure out a workable solution to what I have so far but your solution definitely got me what I needed. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If i rightly understand what you are asking for, this can do it

```
for i in *.*
do
   FL=`head -1 $i`
   echo "$i \"$FL\""
done
```

For your requirement you can try this

```
OP_FILE="op.csv"
>$OP_FILE
for i in 328*.*
do
  FL=`head -1 $i`
  echo "$i \"$FL\"" >> $OP_FILE
done
```

Comment: Thats actually exactly what I needed. I do have a couple of questions however. How would I specify the files I'm looking for? For example only looking for files that start with "328". I know in general to use a wild card such as '*', but where would I actually put that in the function? Also, how would I go about outputting all of that to a csv? Where would I put the "> files.csv"?

Comment: For some reason its not appending the output to the file, it looks like its overwritting it since there is only one line of output in the file and I'm expecting about 50 with the test batch I'm using. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running the script multiple times or only once?

Comment: Just running it once. It outputs all of the lines to the command line when I take out the append at the end. But when the append is on there its only writing the first result to the file.

Comment: Think I figured out the issue. Seems to be something compatibilitywise going on between Linux and Excel in Windows. Reads fine when I cat the file from Linux in the command line

Comment: this works, and is clearer, but i must add that the awk solution above is significantly faster.